# problems sending data with Curl and file_get_content php

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I try to post data via cURL or `file_get_contents`, the problem is when I send data from my local host server to my own server(production server), the data post correctly, but when I try with other server (it's for testing) the data is not posting.

Here's my PHP file to send data:

```
$json = array(
    'Shop' =>$url,
    'order_number' => $referencia,
    'status' => $status,
    'payment' => $t_pago,
    'shipping_method' => $carrierData,
    'costo_envio' => $costo_envio,
    'products' =>$products,
    'total_weight' => $orderWeight,
    'firstname' => $firstname,
    'lastname' => $lastname,
    'address1' => $address1,
    'address2' => $address2,
    'postcode' => $postcode,
    'country' => $country,
    'city' => $city,
    'phone' => $phone,
    'email' => $email,
    'note' => $orderMessage, 
);

if($params['newOrderStatus']->id == 4) {

    $data = json_encode($json);
    $ch = curl_init('http://api.com/prestashop/shipping.php');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

This is the code with `file_get_content`:

```
$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => json_encode( $json ),
        'header'=>  "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" . "Accept: application/json\r\n"
    )
);

$context  = stream_context_create( $options );
$response = file_get_contents( $url_99, false, $context );
```

Here's the code that receive the JSON: [code](http://paste.ofcode.org/sbhFt63XvueqFXsxxhqWfY)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php) is set to 1 in your php.ini configuration file. You can view the current php.ini configuration by using the function `phpinfo();`. This variable sets whether PHP is allowed to open files from remote servers, and will block execution of `file_get_contents()` to remote servers.

Comment: I checked the value and is enable, so i don´t understand why not send data